# Image size increases when uploaded to photoshop (adjusting image size for web purposes)

Tags: image

I'm making a website with a single image as a background (with different backgrounds for subpages). So far I have established that the image should be about 1920x1080, possibly with 1.77:1 aspect ratio and a jpg for PCs. Now I want to reduce the image file size without losing quality.

1) First my problem. I have encountered the most bizarre thing in photoshop. When I upload an image 4272x2848 that weights 521 KB into photoshop and save it without changing anything, its size increases to... 1,52 MB ??? After I cut down the size to ~1920x1080 the size is still ~800 KB. Also the image before uploading has 96 DPI, after it is uploaded it changes to 72 DPI. *(What sorcery is this?)*
2) What is an acceptable image file size with that resolution?
3) Should I use save for web? This increases the size or reduces the quality from what I have experimented.
4) I found this image size reducer website: https://kraken.io/web-interface It reduces the size and I think the image quality does not change.

5) http://www.filedropper.com/pancakes - the image from question #1. (The image will probably be changed in the near future so this one is more of a case study).
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG being lossy, every time you load, then save, a separate JPEG algorithm is applied again.  I believe the default for Photoshop is High quality, which an 8 on their dialog.  So if you have an original JPEG that was originally saved as a low or medium quality (say a 4-6 on the Photoshop dialog), if you then open that in Photoshop, and go with the default "High/8" quality save, then the JPEG algorithm is applied on the perceptual image, meaning you saved a lower quality perceptual image at a higher quality algorithm's amount of data.

This is a major reason that I've moved away from JPEG.  If JPEG is required I always try to start with either a RAW, BMP, TIFF, or PNG image, and then save off a JPEG version from that, then if I need to make any changes I go back to the full "original" [lossless] format, make the changes then save the JPEG again.  I try to never edit an image that is already saved as JPEG, because you're always going to lose a small amount of quality (mostly the JPEG algorithm is good enough that the loss of quality isn't perceptual, but the file size can change none-the-less).

Comment: Now that you said that it actually makes sense. So how do I crop and resize the image without opening it in photoshop? Should I try to adjust the jpg quality to something like 4-8 to match the original's quality? Can I trust what i see, i. e. if I see no changes is that ok or will the artifacts show up somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, if you're stuck with JPEG as the original, then experiment with lowering the "quality" in Photoshop until you find a match.  Do you have any way of getting hold of the "original" image in a lossless format like RAW/BMP etc?  If so, that is always your best bet.  If not, then find the largest original JPEG version that you can, and then edit/crop and save a lower settings. You can also just use the original image, and use CSS Cover to expand the image to fill the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I'm stuck with a JPEG but I think I know what to do now. I use CSS cover but I believe I still need to lower the image size.